# SymPy diff function on cosec(x) is returning Derivative(cosec(x),x)

Tags: python, sympy

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
print(diff("cosec(x)","x"))
```

The output I got is:
`Derivative(cosec(x), x)`

What is up with this and how do I actually get the derivative of cosec(x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the symbol `x`:

```
x = Symbol('x')
```

then you can obtain the derivative as

```
diff(csc(x),x)
```

As you can see the name of cosecant function is `csc`